# Selecionar somente tuplas de uma tabela com JOIN

Tags: sql-server

Possuo a seguinte query:

```
SELECT finpag.cod_forn 
      ,sicforn.nome
      ,finpag.data_pagto 
      ,finempe.cod_reduzido 
      ,finpag.num_empenho 
      ,finpag.ano_empenho 
      ,num_liquid 
      ,ano_liquid 
      ,valor_transacao 
 FROM finpag 
 INNER JOIN sicforn on 
       sicforn.cod_forn = finpag.cod_forn 
 INNER JOIN finempe on
       (finempe.num_empenho = finpag.num_empenho) 
 WHERE  finpag.data_pagto between '1-1-1997' and '31-12-1997' and finpag.cod_forn = 1840 and finpag.ano_empenho = 97
 ORDER BY finpag.num_liquid
```

Que me retorna a seguinte consulta:

```
cod_forn/nome/cod_reduzido/num_empenho/ano_empenho/num_liquid/ano_liquid/valor_transacao

1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 286 1473    97  3554    97  734
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 3   1473    97  3554    97  734
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 2   1661    97  3671    97  649
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 370 1661    97  3671    97  649
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 370 1661    97  3903    97  85
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 2   1661    97  3903    97  85
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 39  1712    97  3942    97  649
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 3   1712    97  3942    97  649
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 3   1712    97  4143    97  85
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 39  1712    97  4143    97  85
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 61  1889    97  3894    97  64
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 348 1889    97  3894    97  64
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 136 2165    97  4571    97  176
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 10  2165    97  4571    97  176
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 58  2010    97  4331    97  562
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 61  2010    97  4331    97  562
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 53  2286    97  5111    97  70
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 264 2286    97  5111    97  70
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 285 1919    97  5714    97  734
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 64  1919    97  5714    97  734
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 17  2534    97  5277    97  78
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 78  2534    97  5277    97  78
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 25  2928    97  6612    97  1080
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 227 2928    97  6612    97  1080
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 17  2773    97  6904    97  130,5
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 10  2773    97  6904    97  130,5
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 389 2513    97  6621    97  575
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 348 2513    97  6621    97  575
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 109 2965    97  6762    97  549
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 53  2965    97  6762    97  549
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 12  2994    97  6763    97  549
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 188 2994    97  6763    97  549
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 10  2773    97  6960    97  156,6
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 17  2773    97  6960    97  156,6
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 49  2657    97  6912    97  1500
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 31  2657    97  6912    97  1500
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 264 3630    97  7698    97  249
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 3   3630    97  7698    97  249
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 188 2994    97  7198    97  1389
1840    LUC'S ELETRODOMESTICOS LTDA 12  2994    97  7198    97  1389
```

Preciso remover as duplicatas, como poderia ser feito (sem utilizar função de agregação)?

Comment: se entendi bem você tem o retorno (condições) esperado; então seria o caso só controlar os campos que seleciona, não?! Você está trazendo `finempe.cod_reduzido`, bastaria remover ele (e outros campos da tabela `finempe` que estejam lá)

Comment: os dados estão duplicados justamente por causa do finempe.cod_reduzido (não existe uma coluna cod_reduzido em finpag), pois são diferentes na tabela finempe e finpag, então gostaria de selecionar somente os da tabela finpag

Comment: Está um tanto confuso a sua questão, mas até onde entendi, adicione na condição do JOIN entre as tabelas FINEMPE e FINPAG o campo cod_reduzido. {INNER JOIN FINEMPE ON (FINEMPE.NUM_EMPENHO = FINPAG.NUM_EMPENHO AND FINEMPE.COD_REDUZIDO = FINPAG.COD_REDUZIDO)}

Comment: @Andrey não existe uma coluna cod_reduzido em finpag, se vc observar a query eu busco ela da finempe

Comment: Então coloque os campos num GROUP BY e faça um MAX do COD_REDUZIDO.

Comment: @Andrey vc poderia exemplificar numa resposta? iria facilitar o meu entendimento

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o SQL abaixo resolva seu problema:

```
SELECT finpag.cod_forn 
          ,sicforn.nome
          ,finpag.data_pagto 
          ,MAX(finempe.cod_reduzido) AS cod_reduzido
          ,finpag.num_empenho 
          ,finpag.ano_empenho 
          ,num_liquid 
          ,ano_liquid 
          ,valor_transacao 
     FROM finpag 
     INNER JOIN sicforn on 
           sicforn.cod_forn = finpag.cod_forn 
     INNER JOIN finempe on
           (finempe.num_empenho = finpag.num_empenho) 
     WHERE  finpag.data_pagto between '1-1-1997' and '31-12-1997' and finpag.cod_forn = 1840 and finpag.ano_empenho = 97
  GROUP BY finpag.cod_forn 
          ,sicforn.nome
          ,finpag.data_pagto 
          ,finpag.num_empenho 
          ,finpag.ano_empenho 
          ,num_liquid 
          ,ano_liquid 
          ,valor_transacao 
     ORDER BY finpag.num_liquid
```

Comment: é isso mesmo... mas ainda deu umas inconsistências aqui... Acho que nem MIN e nem o MAX iriam servir,  o que poderia colocar ao invés deles?

Comment: Podes explicar qual a inconsistência? Pode ser qualquer função de agregação, MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM... depende do seu objetivo final.

Comment: ele realmente retirou as duplicatas, mas a lógica de selecionar o maior ou o menor cod_reduzido não está correta

Comment: Deixa eu entender melhor sua realidade, a tabela finemp é sua tabela de empresas cadastradas? Se sim, quantas empresas tem cadastradas? Talvez falte apenas aplicar um Where no seu SQL original para delimitar a trazer apenas um registro da tabela finemp...

Comment: É mais ou menos por aí, essa consulta retorna os gastos realizados em com outras empresas porém na tabela finempe não possuo o nome da empresa ( pego no inner join com sicforn) e também não possou o cod_reduzido (pego no inner join com finempe)

Comment: Poste por favor a estrutura das tabelas: finpag, finempe e sicforn... ao menos as chaves existentes nessas tabelas

Comment: tá lá as colunas das tabelas

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72734/discussion-between-andrey-and-v-avancini).

Answer (score 1):

#### Solução

No seu caso em questão, provavelmente o `RIGHT JOIN` que é o que precisa, pois busca somente os valores correlacionados que estão na sua "tabela direita", ou seja, no seu join `RIGHT`.

---

#### Conceito

Basicamente você tem que entender o conceito da esquerda e direita (left e right), por exemplo:

A sua tabela em FROM ela é a sua tabela esquerda, ou seja, `LEFT`, quando for fazer um `JOIN`.

```
FROM tabela1 X
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Ou seja, você está trazendo tudo da tabela X, mais os registros da Y que tem vínculo com a X.

Agora em:

```
FROM tabela1 X
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Você trás tudo que está na sua tabela da direita "Y" mais os de "X" que tem relação com "Y".

O `INNER` somente o que for em comum nas 2 tabelas, e o `FULL` trás TUDO independente das relações.

Existe muito material sobre isso, e principalmente essa imagem super conhecida que ajuda muito no entendimento:

[image: tab]

---

#### edit

> Preciso remover as duplicatas, como poderia ser feito (sem utilizar
>   função de agregação)?

Com essa citação após a edição, muda o contexto.
Neste caso deve-se usar o `GROUP BY`

Comment: nem left nem rigth aplicam quaisquer mudanças no resultado.

Comment: Agora com essa citação que fez: `Preciso remover as duplicatas, como poderia ser feito (sem utilizar função de agregação)?` entendi. Mas nesse caso somente com o `GROUP BY`

Comment: assim como exemplificado na resposta acima?

Comment: Como na resposta do Andrey. Você tem que saber o que você quer unir, e então definir todos os campos. Se nunca fez ou tem ainda certa dúvida, cria um banco para teste, faça por partes. É mais fácil aprender dirigir num carro do que uma carreta ! rsrs Se ainda ficarem dúvidas, posta seu banco no http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: eu acho que vc não entendeu meu brm rsrs eu NÃO gostaria de usar função de agregação, o group by vem justamente para utiliza-las, certo?

Comment: Entendi sim ! rs Por isso que disse `Mas nesse caso somente com o GROUP BY` !  Os registros vem no seu filtro, para uni-los somente dessa forma. Eu não vejo outra forma. Você viu algo que faça da forma que você quer ? Se tiver exemplos passa que vemos !