# Select com resultado errado

Tags: postgresql

Possuo o seguinte select:

```
SELECT suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao, capacidade, 
count(public.estoque.codigosuprimento) quantidade,estoqueminimo, sum (valorunitario) valor
FROM public.estoque,public.tiposuprimento, public.suprimento
WHERE public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo and 
public.tiposuprimento.codigo = public.suprimento.codigotiposuprimento and usado = '0' 
  AND codigosuprimento = 155
GROUP BY suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao,capacidade,estoqueminimo
ORDER BY suprimento
```

Que me retorna corretamente as seguintes informações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso adicionar quais equipamentos são compatíveis com esse suprimento, para isso criei a seguinte *Query*

```
SELECT codigosuprimento, array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' | ') AS modelo
FROM public.modelosuprimento, public.impressoramodelo 
WHERE public.impressoramodelo.codigo = public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo
  AND codigosuprimento = 155
GROUP BY codigosuprimento;
```

E ela me retorna os equipamentos corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém não estou conseguindo unir essas *Querys* ou faze-las em um select apenas, sempre que tento adaptar para um select só meu resultado é inconsistente com as informações corretas. Já tentei da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao, capacidade, 
count(public.estoque.codigosuprimento) quantidade,estoqueminimo, sum (valorunitario) valor,
array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' | ') AS modelo
FROM public.estoque,public.tiposuprimento, public.suprimento, public.modelosuprimento, public.impressoramodelo
WHERE public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo 
  AND public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.modelosuprimento.codigosuprimento 
  AND public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo = public.impressoramodelo.codigo
  AND public.tiposuprimento.codigo = public.suprimento.codigotiposuprimento
  AND usado = '0'
  AND public.modelosuprimento.codigosuprimento = 155
GROUP BY suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao,capacidade,estoqueminimo
ORDER BY suprimento
```

E obtive o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que está incorreto, se tiverem alguma ideia de o que estou fazendo errado ou alguma dica de como alcançar esse objetivo, agradeço.

Comment: Em vista o problema é que você está usando `WHERE` para relacionar as tabelas, e se caso 1 delas não tiver correspondência, o valor não é retornado. Utilize `JOINS` para fazer essa união. Se tiver isso no sqlfiddle faço o select para você.

Comment: @RBZ como posso substituir por JOIN nesse caso?

Comment: Você precisa baixar o script do banco, com a criação das tabelas, inserts, etc, assim ele gera seu banco no fiddle, aí você passa o link. http://sqlfiddle.com/ , exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1

Comment: @RBZ Tu teria como colocar um exemplo de como utilizar o JOIN dai eu adapto para minha necessidade?

Comment: posta a estrutura das tabelas

Comment: @R.Santos Publiquei como resposta. Dê uma olhada em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274433/selecionar-somente-tuplas-de-uma-tabela-com-join/274447#274447

Answer (score 1):

Em vista o problema é que você está usando `WHERE` para relacionar as tabelas, e se caso 1 delas não tiver correspondência, o valor não é retornado. Utilize `JOINS` para fazer essa união.

Basicamente você tem que entender o conceito da esquerda e direita (left e right), por exemplo:

A sua tabela em `FROM` ela é a sua tabela esquerda, ou seja, `LEFT`, quando for fazer um `JOIN`.

```
FROM tabela1 X
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Ou seja, você está trazendo tudo da tabela X, mais os registros da Y que tem vínculo com a X.

Agora em:

```
FROM tabela1 X
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Você trás tudo que está na sua tabela da direita "Y" mais os de "X" que tem relação com "Y".

O `INNER` somente o que for em comum nas 2 tabelas, e o `FULL` trás TUDO independente das relações.

[Link#1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247921/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-join-e-where/247942#247942)
[Link#2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274433/selecionar-somente-tuplas-de-uma-tabela-com-join/274447#274447)

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema realizando um subSelect:

```
SELECT public.estoque.codigosuprimento as cod ,suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao, capacidade, 
count(public.estoque.codigosuprimento) quantidade,estoqueminimo, sum (valorunitario) valor, (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(modelo),' | ') AS modelo
FROM public.modelosuprimento, public.impressoramodelo where 
public.impressoramodelo.codigo = public.modelosuprimento.codigomodelo and codigosuprimento = public.estoque.codigosuprimento group by codigosuprimento)
FROM public.estoque,public.tiposuprimento, public.suprimento
where public.estoque.codigosuprimento = public.suprimento.codigo and 
public.tiposuprimento.codigo = public.suprimento.codigotiposuprimento and usado = '0' 
group by suprimento, public.tiposuprimento.descricao,capacidade,estoqueminimo,public.estoque.codigosuprimento
order by suprimento
```