# Join SQL server

Tags: sql, servidor, join

Boa tarde, comecei a trabalhar com sql a 3 mesês e estou apanhando em uma aplicação.

Tenho 3 tables as quais tenho informações associados pelo "registro"

Gostaria de pegar todas as informações da primeira table chamada configuracao mesmo que não esteja associada as outras tables dividas e registros.

```
sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM dividas a 
    LEFT JOIN registros r on (a.registro = r.registro)  
    INNER JOIN configuracao b on r.registro = b.registro 
    WHERE a.empresa='" & LEFT(Combo1.Text, 2) & "' 
    ORDER BY r.registro"
```

Nesse query ele traz a informação se tiver informação de registro nas 3 tables, quero que traga também as informações que só tem em "configuracao" mesmo que não tenha em "dividas" e "registros"

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Obrigado!

Comment: Tem como nos mostrar o relacionamento entre as tabelas?

Comment: Como não sei o modelo vou adicionar aqui, se resolver jogo em resposta, tente a seguinte qury: `Select 
 * 
from configuracao b
 LEFT Join registros r  on r.registro = b.registro 
 LEFT join dividas a   on a.registro = r.registro
where a.empresa='" & Left(Combo1.Text, 2) & "' 
order by r.registro`

Comment: Rodrigo, é MUITO importante entender bem os JOINS (`LEFT, INNER, RIGHT, FULL`). O ideal antes de tudo, seria você entender eles, tentar fazer (o que eu tenho certeza que irá conseguir). Essa afirmação "se tiver informação de registro nas 3 tables" pode ser que esteja incorreta, pois você tem um "LEFT" da tabela `registros`, então trará os registros independente se tiver ou não na tabela `dividas`. Conte conosco para ajudá-lo. Olhe essa tabela de JOINS que irá lhe ajudar: [Link 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274447/92908), [Link 2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/247942/92908) ✌️

Comment: Bom dia, primeiramente obrigado pelas dicas..
Tentei o query e ele me trouxe a mesma resposta, vou enviar o grid de cada tabela:
configuracao(que é a que eu quero trazer tudo)
Obs: Os registros 3700 e 3800 só estão nessa tabela e são esses que não aparecem nas outras.
REG NOME DT ADM STATUS DT DEM PAG

3000 BELTRANO X Y Z B
3700 NOMECONFIG X Y Z B
3800 NOMECONFIG2 X Y Z B
3300 NOMEQUALQUER X Y Z B
Na tabela registros e dividas vem todas informações menos o 3700 e 3800.
ñ consegui enviar uma imagem para explicar melhor, posso enviar via e-mail se ficar difícil de entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando apenas o código que você passou, pode tentar a seguinte consulta:

```
sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM configuracao b
    LEFT JOIN dividas a on b.registro = a.registro and a.empresa='" & LEFT(Combo1.Text, 2) & "' 
    LEFT JOIN registros r on (a.registro = r.registro)  
    ORDER BY r.registro"
```

Apenas movi `configuracao` para ser a tabela principal da consulta. Fazendo um [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.devmedia.com.br/clausulas-inner-join-left-join-e-right-join-no-sql-server/18930) com as outras tabelas; ou seja, caso exista alguma ocorrência na tabela de `configuracao` ele trará o valor retornado.

Porém essa mudança obriga a mover também sua condição do `WHERE a.empresa='" & LEFT(Combo1.Text, 2) & "'` para o *join* da tabela `dividas` (se mantivermos a condição ele apenas trará um retorno se existir alguém em `dividas` que atenda a condição).

Apenas como observação, a consulta da pergunta faz um *left join* com `registros` e um *inner join* com `configuracao`; em outras palavras, ele traz um retorno caso existam ocorrências em `dividas` e em `configuracao` (apenas não sendo necessária ocorrência na tabela `registros`).

Comment: Boa pessoal, consegui resolver o problema com esse query
    sql = "SELECT *   FROM configuracao b   LEFT JOIN dividas a on (b.registro = a.registro) and a.empresa='" & Left(Combo1.Text, 2) & "'  LEFT JOIN registros r on (b.registro = r.registro)    ORDER BY b.registro"

Foi no chute, ainda não o analisei pra entender melhor pois preciso terminar essa aplicação logo.

Obrigado a todos !!!

Comment: @RodrigoMerce, aparentemente a dica que dei resolveu teu problema. Sendo assim, podes marcar a [**resposta como correta**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Caso precises de alguma ajuda a mais para entender a solução, é só chamar!

Comment: Posso comentar aqui uma outra dúvida do mesmo query ou preciso abrir outra questão ?

Comment: idealmente é bom abrir outra pergunta, pra não "poluir". Acabei de ler [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7256/o-que-%C3%A9-o-stack-overflow) que fala sobre deixar os _posts_ mais limpos ;)