# Como fazer Sub Select em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar, pois não consegui fazer o comando sub select entre duas tabelas, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Preciso puxar o nome do livro que está na tabela livro junto com os dados da tabela de vendas.

Tabela `vendas`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela `livros`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: não seria um join e não um subselect?

Comment: Se não me engano o comando para fazer isso é o `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Respondendo sua pergunta:

O que você deseja **não é subselect** e sim `JOIN`.

Exemplo de `JOIN` considerando que sua tabela venda sempre terá 1 livro referente a venda:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VENDAS VD
INNER JOIN LIVROS LV ON LV.IDLIVRO = VD.IDLIVRO
```

Filtrando alguns campos:

```
SELECT VD.IDVENDA, LV.TITULO, LV.PRECO
FROM VENDAS VD
JOIN LIVROS LV ON LV.IDLIVRO = VD.IDLIVRO
```

*(Nos exemplos veja que usei `INNER JOIN` e `JOIN`. Nesse caso funciona da mesma forma, pois usando somente `JOIN` ele assume como se fosse `INNER`.)*

---

#### Exemplos extra:

Para trazer **TODOS** valores da **tabela `VENDAS`** mesmo que **não** tenha preenchido o campo `IDLIVRO` na tabela `VENDAS`, use o `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VENDAS VD
LEFT JOIN LIVROS LV ON LV.IDLIVRO = VD.IDLIVRO
```

Para trazer **TODOS** valores da **tabela `LIVROS`** mesmo que **não** tenha preenchido o campo `IDLIVRO` na tabela `VENDAS`, use o `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VENDAS VD
RIGHT JOIN LIVROS LV ON LV.IDLIVRO = VD.IDLIVRO
```

---

Referência sobre `JOINS` que seria legal ver como exemplo:

[Selecionar somente tuplas de uma tabela com JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/274447/92908)

Comment: Obrigado cara :D, falei select pois foi isso que o professor ensinou, mas vi que pelo seu metodo é bem mais facil :D.

Comment: @leandror o que fiz foi um `select` (consulta, query). O que está errado é dizer "subquery". Isso é outra coisa para outra finalidade. ✌️

Comment: @leandror ficou alguma dúvida? Caso não, escolha uma resposta e marque-a: [COMO MARCAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

O join seria uma solução conforme mencionado acima, você também pode fazer o seguinte:

```
select * from Vendas
where idlivro in (
  select idlivro from livros where idgenero = 1
);
```

Comment: diego, está totalmente incorreto sua resposta. Principalmente isso: `in ( select idlivro where idgenero = 1 );` que não tem nem a tabela. Tente sempre que for publicar uma resposta, colocar bem detalhado, pois isso ajuda evitarmos errá-las.

Comment: @rbz cara não entendi o porque de dizer que está errado, isso é um subselect, não é o ideal de se fazer entendo que é mais moroso para o banco, mas é uma forma de se fazer sem utilizar join.

Comment: diego, seu select não é o que o foi pedido na pergunta, e ao menos funciona, como mostrei o trecho no comentário acima.

Comment: @diego seu _subselect_ não funciona basicamente porque não tem `from`; se você adicionar e corrigir, talvez passe a ser uma alternativa válida.

Comment: @rLinhares valeu, não tinha percebido que havia esquecido o from