# PHP SQL Inner Join - Mostrar nome ao invés do número ID

Tags: php, sql

Estou tendo uma pequena dificuldade com relação a query INNER JOIN. Possuo uma tabela chamada users e nela contém os seguintes campos:

```
First Name
Last Name
Tipo_fk (Foreing Key)
Categoria_fk (Foreing Key)
```

Como mostrado acima a função select do HTML funciona bem porém quando carrego a minha tabela para mostrar os dados cadastrados, os campos "Tipo" e "Categoria" mostram o número ID do valor selecionado na combobox ao invés do nome selecionado.

Abaixo segue a query (INNER JOIN) que estou utilizando para tentar mostrar o nome ao invés do número ID do ítem selecionado.

```
SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.tipo_id , categorias.categoria_id
FROM ((users
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoria_id)
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipo_id)
```

E um trecho da tabela no qual mencionei que mostra apenas o número ID do valor selecionado na droplist após cadastrado:

[image: Tabela mostrando número ID ao invés do nome]

Comment: Ao invés do ´id` das `categorias` e `tipo_ps` pretende mostrar o quê exatamente?

Comment: Nessa campo você está a apresentar o ID do tipo e o ID da categoria. Veja quais os campos que a sua query devolve, e depois altere no html em vez de mostrar os IDs, troque pelos campos que pretende.

Comment: Olá João e Luís. Obrigado pelo retorno. Então, o que pretendo é que ao preencher um formulário e salvá-lo depois usando o (insert into), esses dados fossem salvos e mostrados em uma tabela. Neste caso eu consigo fazer isso porém na tabela é mostrado o número ID do valor contido na droplist ao invés do nome em si. No campo (tipo_ps) eu tenho: (ID 1) -> Produto e (ID 2) -> Serviço e no campo (categoria_fk) eu tenho (ID 1) -> Metais, (ID 2) -> Consultoria e (ID 3) -> Eletrônicos.

Comment: No html estou usando: <select name="tipo_fk" class="form-control">
  <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['tipo_id']; ?>"><?= $row['tipo']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Não entendi porque tantos parênteses. Como são desnecessários, os tirei.*

---

#### Solução:

```
SELECT u.*, cat.nome as categoria, tip.nome as tipo
FROM users u
INNER JOIN categorias cat ON cat.categoria_id = u.categoria_fk
INNER JOIN tipo_ps tip ON tipo_ps.tipo_id = u.tipo_fk
```

---

#### Explicando:

Quando você faz o `JOIN` você está ligando as tabelas, onde terá acesso aos registros e todos os campos relacionados.

Para filtrar os campos que quer, você deve colocar a `tabela.nomedocampo`.

No select feito, em `cat.nome as categoria`, estou trazendo o valor do campo `nome` da tabela `categorias`.

Em `tip.nome as tipo`, a mesma coisa, só que buscando da tabela `tipo_ps`.

---

#### Mais detalhes:

É importante saber a relação entre suas tabelas, pois utilizando o `INNER JOIN`, você somente trará os valores contidos em ambas tabelas, ou seja, se houver um registro na tabela principal sem o campo da `FK` preenchido, já não trará o registro, e vice-versa.

Isso é criterioso em relatórios do que usaria uma contagem (`count`) sem filtro, e ao tirar uma relação de registro com o `INNER JOIN`, assim os valores não bateriam se não estivessem 100% relacionadas.

---

#### Extras:

[Uma breve explicação sobre Inner, Left, Right, Outer/Full e Cross Join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)

[Selecionar somente tuplas de uma tabela com JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274433/selecionar-somente-tuplas-de-uma-tabela-com-join/274447#274447)

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação rbz. Ajustei o código e funcionou :)

Answer (score 2):

Você apenas precisa alterar o campo de retorno da sua consulta; a junção entre as tabelas parece estar sendo feita da forma correta, então bastaria retornar a descrição de *tipo* e *categoria* ao invés do *id*:

```
SELECT users.*, tipo_ps.descricao , categorias.descricao
FROM ((users
INNER JOIN categorias ON users.categoria_fk = categorias.categoria_id)
INNER JOIN tipo_ps ON users.tipo_fk = tipo_ps.tipo_id)
```

**detalhe**: apenas observe qual o nome do campo nas tabelas `tipo_ps` e `categorias` que contém a descrição de cada uma (na consulta, referenciados como `descricao`)

Comment: Obrigad pela ajuda rLinhares. Ajustei o código baseando nas informações de vocês e consegui. Valeu! :)